# PHP mysqli query doesn't return any results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using this code here

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
$servername = '127.0.0.1';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'splafpoo_users';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("<b>Connection failed:</b> %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
} 

$key = '';

if(isset($_POST['key'])){
    $key = $_POST['key'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE serial='$key'";
echo $query;

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row;
?>
```

Running the query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE serial='test'` in phpMyAdmin returns the desired result however when trying to display the result using the code above nothing is displayed and I cannot figure out how. How do I display the result?

Comment: It's worth noting that your code is wide open to SQL injection.  You should definitely use query parameters instead of executing user input as code.

Comment: Put the query *inside* your `if` statement so you do not run it if `$key` is not set. You're not getting any results because `$key` is set to blank and you have no records in your database where `$key = '';` You are running this query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE serial=''` instead of one where `$key` has a value.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I inserted the appropriate inside the IF statement and I do have a row that contains what I am looking for. To test I use a python script which sends the post request with the data 'key': 'test'. Here's a screenshot of my the query result in phpmyadmin http://i.imgur.com/n29UrK9.png

Comment: You manually set the variable to `test` but you're not checking `$key` inside your `if` condition.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna need a good old fashion while loop

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['WHATEVERCOLUMNITISYOUWANT'];
}
```

also this is most definitely a duplicate.

Comment: If there was a row that matched the echo the OP has would work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var_dump($row)` instead of `echo $row` or you use echo with a key:
e.g. `echo $row["user"]`